# Adding 1 everytime i use button vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Basically, I need 2 make a student number and after every new entry I put the student number should +1 so 20182(or 3 if male)001 will be 20182(or 3 if male)002 after I push the button and it must keep +1 but once it reaches the 10th registered student the format changes to 20182(3 if male)010.

I have done everything but make the number +1 every time I use the button
so basically the answer must be:

```
Student Number is 20182001
Surname , Name
contact details
```

but, I done everything besides the `001, 002,003` till 010 part so if anybody could help I would be thankful

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Number As Integer = 2018000
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strSurname As String
    Dim strFullName As String
    Dim strContact As String
    Dim strGender As String
    Dim x As Integer

    'IF statement'

    If Me.cboGender.SelectedItem = "Female" Then
        Number = 2018300
    Else
    End If
    If Me.cboGender.SelectedItem = "Male" Then
        Number = 2018200
    Else
    End If

    'Finding The Student Number'

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do While (i < 1)

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If i = 201820010 Then
        Number = 201800
    Else
        If i = 201830010 Then
            Number = 201800
            End if
        End If
    'Add Items To ListBox'
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Student number: " & Number & i)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(txtSurname.Text & " , " & txtFullName.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(txtContact.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("============================================")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Think a little about what you wrote. i equals 0. Next Do while i is less than 1. Now i is less than one so the loop executes. Now i plus one (0+1)  is assigned to i. Now i is one and Loop. Is i less than 1. No, it is now equal to one. Exits the loop and goes on to the If statements. i is for all time and eternity (till the end of the sub) going to be 1 so it will never =201820010 or 201830010 (which BTW has an extra digit) which makes your If statements useless. Please learn to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code was doing, but based on your requirements:

```
Public baseFemale  As Integer = 20182000
Public baseMale As Integer = 20183000
Public autoNumber As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Number as Integer;

    autoNumber = autoNumber + 1

    If Me.cboGender.SelectedItem = "Female" Then
        Number = baseFemale + autoNumber
    Else
        Number = baseMale + autoNumber
    Else

    'Add Items To ListBox'
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Student number: " & Number & i)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(txtSurname.Text & " , " & txtFullName.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(txtContact.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("============================================")

End Sub
```

Additionally you may want to check for autoNumber exceeding 999 - but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you so much i have looked at your autonumber  and seen where i made my mistakes with my loop for i and I will make sure the number doesnt go over 999 thank you very much.